# Expect toContain text from a set of values in jest,enzyme with React

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

My below test works,

```
let output = mount(story);
      expect(output.text()).toContain('Superman');
```

But I need to even alllow Batman and Spiderman to pass:
I need to check if output.text() has either 
-> ['Superman','Batman','Spiderman']

Can't do it with

```
expect(output.text()).toContain(['Superman','Batman','Spiderman']);
```

output.text() willl contain "Superman is the best" or "Spiderman is the best"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can add your own matcher](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectextendmatchers) instead of `toContain`.

```
expect.extend({
  toContainHero(text) {
    let pass = false;
    const heroes = ['Superman','Batman','Spiderman'];
    heroes.forEach((hero) => {
      pass = text.indexOf(hero) !== -1;
    })
    if (pass) {
      return {
        message: () =>
          `expected hero to be found`,
        pass: true,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () => `expected hero to be not found`,
        pass: false,
      };
    }
  },
});
```

And then do:

```
expect(output.text()).toContainHero();
```

Comment: thanks, just made sure pass once true is not overwritten

` 
 toContainHero(text) {
    let pass = false;
    const heroes = ['Superman','Batman','Spiderman'];
    heroes.forEach((hero) => {
      ( pass = pass ?pass : text.indexOf(hero) !== -1);
    })
    if (pass) {
      return {
        message: () =>
          `expected hero to be found`,
        pass: true,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () => `expected hero to be not found`,
        pass: false,
      };
    }
  },
});
expect(output.text()).toContainHero();
`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this is better answer for you :

```
expect(output.text()).toEqual(expect.stringMatching(/^(Batman|Superman|Spiderman)/));
```